# Examples of Algorithms which has O(1), O(n log n) and O(log n) complexities

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

What are some algorithms which we use daily that has O(1), O(n log n) and O(log n) complexities?

Comment: Why wiki? It's neither a poll nor subjective. She wants specific examples of the big-O properties.

Comment: Wiki because it has no single correct answer, it has multiple answers.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good list, too.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Answer (score 332, accepted):

If you want examples of Algorithms/Group of Statements with Time complexity as given in the question, here is a small list -

## `O(1)` time

- Accessing Array Index (int a = ARR[5];)
- Inserting a node in Linked List
- Pushing and Poping on Stack
- Insertion and Removal from Queue
- Finding out the parent or left/right child of a node in a tree stored in Array
- Jumping to Next/Previous element in Doubly Linked List

## `O(n)` time

In a nutshell, all Brute Force Algorithms, or Noob ones which require linearity, are based on O(n) time complexity

- Traversing an array
- Traversing a linked list
- Linear Search
- Deletion of a specific element in a Linked List (Not sorted)
- Comparing two strings
- Checking for Palindrome
- Counting/Bucket Sort
  and here too you can find a million more such examples....

---

## `O(log n)` time

- Binary Search
- Finding largest/smallest number in a binary search tree
- Certain Divide and Conquer Algorithms based on Linear functionality
- Calculating Fibonacci Numbers - Best Method
  The basic premise here is NOT using the complete data, and reducing the problem size with every iteration

---

## `O(n log n)` time

The factor of 'log n' is introduced by bringing into consideration Divide and Conquer. Some of these algorithms are the best optimized ones and used frequently.

- Merge Sort
- Heap Sort
- Quick Sort
- Certain Divide and Conquer Algorithms based on optimizing O(n^2) algorithms

---

## `O(n^2)` time

These ones are supposed to be the less efficient algorithms if their O(nlogn) counterparts are present. The general application may be Brute Force here.

- Bubble Sort
- Insertion Sort
- Selection Sort
- Traversing a simple 2D array

---

## `O(n!)` time

- Solving the travelling salesman problem via brute-force search
- generating all unrestricted permutations of a partially ordered set;
- finding the determinant with Laplace expansion
- enumerating all partitions of a set

Comment: What about n!? I've been wondering what common algorithm uses n!?

Comment: Accessing a HashMap value as well as more complex algorithms like an LRU implementation which achieve O(1) using a HashMap and a doubly-linked-list or implementing a stack with PUSH/POP/MIN functionality. Also the recursive implementation of Fibonacci fall under N!.

Comment: Also, finding a^n is O (log n). A good example in liang's introduction to java programming book

Comment: My OCD wants you to switch the `O(log n)` list to be before the `O(n)` list so that the list is in order from best to worst. haha :)

Comment: Traversing a 2D array is actually O(n x m) unless it's a square matrix.

Comment: Traversing a 2D array is actually O(n), where n is the total number of cells. Even traversing a 666D array is O(n). The "n" is just a reference to the "number of elements" of the input.

Comment: @SamEaton My OCD was about to write the same comment - you made me laught.

Comment: The 'traveling salesman' problem is an example of n! (n factorial) as well

Answer (score 39):

O(1) - most cooking procedures are O(1), that is, it takes a constant amount of time even if there are more people to cook for (to a degree, because you could run out of space in your pot/pans and need to split up the cooking)

O(logn) - finding something in your telephone book. Think binary search.

O(n) - reading a book, where n is the number of pages. It is the minimum amount of time it takes to read a book.

O(nlogn) - cant immediately think of something one might do everyday that is nlogn...unless you sort cards by doing merge or quick sort!

Comment: It takes a lot longer to cook a roast than a mini-roast :-)

Comment: but usually it takes the same time to cook two mini-roast vs one mini-roast, provided your oven is large enough to fit it in!

Comment: Very insightful! I suppose the task of compiling a telephone or address book from a list of names/numbers might be O(n log n)

Comment: An example of O(n log n) that you might do in everyday life: Translating a text by looking up every word in a dictionary.

Answer (score 31):

A simple example of `O(1)` might be `return 23;` -- whatever the input, this will return in a fixed, finite time.

A typical example of `O(N log N)` would be sorting an input array with a good algorithm (e.g. mergesort).

A typical example if `O(log N)` would be looking up a value in a sorted input array by bisection.

Answer (score 9):

I can offer you some general algorithms...

- O(1): Accessing an element in an array (i.e. int i = a[9])
- O(n log n): quick or mergesort (On average)
- O(log n): Binary search

These would be the gut responses as this sounds like homework/interview kind of question. If you are looking for something more concrete it's a little harder as the public in general would have no idea of the underlying implementation (Sparing open source of course) of a popular application, nor does the concept in general apply to an "application"

Answer (score 4):

O(1): finding the best next move in Chess (or Go for that matter). As the number of game states is finite it's only O(1) :-)

Comment: Yes, you can usually trade off time for space. I've actually done this for a tic-tac-toe game since there are only 3^9 states (less if you handle rotations intelligently). Chess, however, has a somewhat larger number of states :-)

Comment: The problem is that I will live only `O(1)` nanoseconds, and you surely know which `O(1)` will occur first...

Answer (score 3):

O(1) - Deleting an element from a doubly linked list. e.g.

```
typedef struct _node {
    struct _node *next;
    struct _node *prev;
    int data;
} node;


void delete(node **head, node *to_delete)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of software application is not measured and is not written in big-O notation.  It is only useful to measure algorithm complexity and to compare algorithms in the same domain.  Most likely, when we say O(n), we mean that it's "O(n) *comparisons*" or  "O(n) arithmetic operations".  That means, you can't compare any pair of algorithms or applications.

Comment: That's not really true. If an algorithm has O(N) time complexity, that means that its runtime is bounded by k * N steps for some constant k. It is not really important whether "steps" are CPU cycles, assembly instructions, or (simple) C operations. That details is hidden by the constant k.

Comment: Not to mention that in many practical cases the "c" of an O(logN) algorithm makes it worse than a simpler O(N) algorithm.

Comment: Haha, yes, and by N we then mean the length of input on a Turing machine tape--which makes vertical form of division take exponential time to implement. :-)  Each domain has its own requirements and its own precinct of abstracting.

Answer (score 2):

You can add following algorithms to your list:

`O(1)` - Determining if a number is even or odd;  Working with HashMap

`O(logN)` - computing x^N,

`O(N Log N)` - Longest increasing subsequence

Answer (score 1):

O (n log n) is famously the upper bound on how fast you can sort an arbitrary set (assuming a standard and not highly parallel computing model).

Answer (score 1):

**O(2<sup>N</sup>)**

O(2<sup>N</sup>) denotes an algorithm whose growth doubles with each additon to the input data set. The growth curve of an O(2<sup>N</sup>) function is exponential - starting off very shallow, then rising meteorically. An example of an O(2<sup>N</sup>) function is the recursive calculation of Fibonacci numbers:

```
int Fibonacci (int number)
{
if (number <= 1) return number;
return Fibonacci(number - 2) + Fibonacci(number - 1);
}
```

Comment: `Tower of Hanoi` would have been a better example.

Answer (score 0):

0(logn)-Binary search, peak element in an array(there can be more than one peak)
0(1)-in python calculating the length of a list or a string. The len() function takes 0(1) time. Accessing an element in an array takes 0(1) time. Push operation in a stack takes 0(1) time.
0(nlogn)-Merge sort. sorting in python takes nlogn time. so when you use listname.sort() it takes nlogn time.

Note-Searching in a hash table sometimes takes more than constant time because of collisions.

Answer (score 0):

**O(1)**

```
DoSomething();
```

**O(n)**

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    DoSomething();
}
```

**O(log n)**

```
for(i=0; i<n; i=i*2){
    DoSomething();
}
```

**O(n log n)**

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
   for(j=0; j<n; j=j*2){
      DoSomething();
   } 
}
```

**O(log^2 n)**

```
for(i=0; i<n; i=i*2){
    for(j=0; j<n; j=j*2){
        DoSomething();
    } 
}
```

**O(n^2)**

```
for(i=0; i<n; i=i++){
    for(j=0; j<n; j=j++){
        DoSomething();
    } 
}
```

**O(2^n)**

```
int DoSomething(int n)
{
    if (n<1) 
       return n;
    return DoSomething(n-1);
}
```