# Big O notation for (c^k)

Tags: java, big-o, time-complexity

The following code give me a O(n). how do I code a for loop that has time complexity of O(c^k)?

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (y%2 == 0)
        return power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
    else
        return x*power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);

}
```

Comment: See the answer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055652/real-world-example-of-exponential-time-complexity

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking, but you can clearly modify this code and win a lot by simply getting rid of repeating recursions (not to calculate the same thing twice recursively).

```
if (y%2 == 0) {
    int res = power(x, y/2);    
    return res * res;
}
```

writing it this way will allow you to write a while loop instead of recursion.

Comment: if (y%2 == 0) {
        int res = power(x, y/2);    
        return res * res;
    }
does this give a O(c^k)?

Comment: is your goal to make the algorithm more complex? why would you need exponential time complexity?

Comment: public void run(int n) { System.out.println(power(3, n)); } public int power(int c, int n) { int result = 1; for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) { result *= n; } return result; } does this code give me a O(c^k) - exponential time complexity?

Comment: no, it gives you O(n). to make it exponential you have to make it way more complex.

Comment: public void run(int n)
    {
        for (long i = 1; i <= power(3, n); i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public int power(int c, int n)
    {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            result *= n;
        }
        return result;
    }

How abt this code?

Comment: no. you should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory

Answer (score 0):

`O(c^k)` - exponential time complexity algorithms are, for example, brute-force search and traveling salesman problems.

I give you an example of brute-force search. If you had a set of characters of length `c`, and have the password of length `k`. Then you would need a `O(c^k)` time to break the password.