# O(3^n) exponential time complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

```
 public void run(int n)
    {
        System.out.println(power(3, n));
    }

public int power(int c, int n)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        result *= n;
    }
    return result;
}
```

does this code give me a O(c^k) - exponential time complexity?

Comment: Short answer, no. Calculating `3^n` does not take `O(3^n)`.

Comment: no offense, but instead of posting your homework one by one read and try by your own... you posted almost same 3 questions in a row

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)` -- there's your complexity. The variable `n` doesn't even come into play here.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It does, if you're doing it wrong (and also in general since O is an upper bound).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big O notation for (c^k)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259996/big-o-notation-for-ck)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, if you feel like showing the guys teaching your course that their problem statement probably isn't what they intended, I would just do it this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) { /*your code here*/}
```

This is in O(c), and since O(c) is a strict subset of O(c<sup>k</sup>) for k > 1, it's also in O(c<sup>k</sup>). That's probably not what the people teaching your course intended, they probably want you to write a loop that runs in Θ(c<sup>k</sup>).

---

On another note:

c<sup>k</sup> and 3<sup>n</sup> are not the same thing. Assuming the length of your input is n, c<sup>k</sup> is constant time while 3<sup>n</sup> is exponential time. Assuming the length of your input is c, c<sup>k</sup> is polynomial while 3<sup>n</sup> is constant. Assuming the length of your input is k, c<sup>k</sup> is exponential while 3<sup>n</sup> is constant.

Answer (score 0):

No calculating 3 raised to the power n is not of complexity O(3^n). Your algorithm complexity is just O(c) as it iterates only c times. To write O(3^n) algorithm, one way can be to run your for loop 3^n times. An example of such for loop is:

```
for(long i = 0; i < Math.power(3, n); i++)
```

Comment: public void run(int n)
    {
        for (long i = 1; i <= power(3, n); i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public int power(int c, int n)
    {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            result *= n;
        }
        return result;
    }

does this also give me O(3^n)?

Comment: Any algorithm which will run for 3^n iterations will generate the same complexity.  Hence this public void run(int n) { for (long i = 1; i <= power(3, n); i++) { System.out.println(i); } } , generates O(3^n) . But this public int power(int c, int n) { int result = 1; for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) { result *= n; } return result; } does not

Comment: @benjamintan - no ... because your `power(c, n)` doesn't compute `c^n`.

Answer (score 0):

> does this code give me a O(c^k) - exponential time complexity?

No.  `power(c, N)` performs `c` multiplications / iterations of the loop, therefore it is O(C).  And that means that (since `c` is a constant in `run(n)`), `test(n)` is actually `O(1)`.

The other thing to note is that `power(c, n)` is computing n<sup>c</sup> NOT c<sup>n</sup>.