# Time complexity of algorithms non polynomial

Tags: time-complexity

Im fairly new to computer science, can anyone give some examples of algorithms which have log complexity or any complexity which are not polynomials such as n, n^2, N^3 etc..

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1592649/14016161

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Examples of Algorithms which has O(1), O(n log n) and O(log n) complexities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592649/examples-of-algorithms-which-has-o1-on-log-n-and-olog-n-complexities)