# What is the time complexity of HashMap insertion and retrieval inside of a for loop?

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity, big-o

I have written this code for an application but I'm having difficulty figuring out if its better than the legacy code (legacy code used one hashmap with List in every value). From what I understand, since Java 8 the insertion and retrieval from a Hashmap is O(log n) and the for loop is O(n) in my case. Am I correct in assuming that the time complexity here would be O(n log n)?

```
//complexity => O(n)
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String s = someList.get(i);
        int someValue = someArray[i];
        if (someCondition < 0) {
            // complexity => O(log n)
            if (hashmap1.containsKey(s)) {
                //complexity => O(log n) + O(log n) = O(log n)
                hashmap1.put(s, hashmap1.get(s) + someValue);
                //complexity => O(log n) + O(log n) = O(log n)
                hashmap2.put(s, hashmap2.get(s) + 1);
            } else {
                //complexity => O(log n)
                hashmap1.put(s, someValue);
                //complexity => O(log n)
                hashmap2.put(s, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: HashMaps generally have O(1) insertion and lookup complexity unless your map degenerated and put everything into one / few buckets. Your loop body is O(1) and therefore the entire thing is O(n). `someList.get(i)` however could be a problem depending on the list implementation, because that may actually not be a constant access.

Comment: Only TreeMap has complexity of O(log n) on insertion and retrieval not Hashmap

Comment: I'm not too worried about the `someList.get(i)` part because it's a very small list with just 12 entries. Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Fclass please consider to accept the answers to improve the community .

Comment: It doesn't affect the complexity, but the `containsKey` if/else can be replaced by `hashmap1.merge(s, someValue, Integer::sum); hashmap2.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's O(n) for traversing the for loop for the elements and O(1) for the HashMap, the final answer is O(n), see more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11611770/15758781).